# How do I call a jq function from vb.net code behind?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I need to call this from the code behind if there is a certain value read in from a 
query string variable ie

```
x as string =  request.querysting("Var")

if x = 'Hide" then

function guestHide()
{
    $(".panel").hide("slow");
}

end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your aspx page do this

```
<%
    if (Request.QueryString["var"].ToString() == "Hide") {
%>
        function guestHide() { $(".panel").hide("slow"); }
<%
    }
%>
```

The above is C#, it should be easily translatable to VB.

Comment: I'm doing this purely from memory, I haven't done VB in forever.

<% IF Request.QueryString("var") = "Hide" Then %>
$(".panel").hide("slow"); }
<% End If %>